# Basic django model question on ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, django-models

I need to create a `model Class` with three columns: network, graduation, and position(s).

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    network = models.ForeignKey(Network)
    graduation = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, choices=choices)
    # position = ?
```

How would I enter in the position column to allow for multiple positions (for example: artist, architect, graphic artist). Note that these positions will not have any related information in their own table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the best way is to go ahead and have a `Position` model (likely using fixtures to populate the rows):

```
class Position(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.label

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    [...]
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position)
```